# PlatformToolset and "deleted function" error (C2280)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

When I upgraded an MFC application from VS2010 to VS2015 recently, essentially two changes were made to the .vcxproj file:

- ToolsVersion="14.0" replaced ToolsVersion="4.0" under `<Project>`
- Each configuration had `<PlatformToolset>v140</PlatformToolset>` added to it

Code that used to compile ok under VS2010 no longer compiles, although it does compile if I reverse the second of these changes. I'm really not clear why. The code -- in which I can't clearly spot a problem -- is essentially this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    union SomeUnion
    {
        struct
        {
            CPoint thisData;    // MFC/ATL type - atltypes.h
            char thatData[ 6 ];
        };
        double otherData;
    };
    void SetSomeStuff( const std::vector<SomeUnion> & someStuff );
    void GetSomeStuff( std::vector<SomeUnion> & someStuff );
};
```

This much is fine -- no errors when compiled with or without `PlatformToolset` under VS2015 (or under VS2010). The error comes when I try to invoke a constructor for `SomeClass::SomeUnion::SomeUnion( void )` in the `GetSomeStuff()` function body with something like this:

```
void SomeClass::GetSomeStuff( std::vector<SomeUnion> & someStuff )
{
    someStuff.resize( 2 );  // error C2280 depending on compiler??
}
```

My guess is that using `PlatformToolset` set to `v140` enforces new rules for unions (possibly in C++11?) that mean that some constructor or assignment operator is now mandatorily defined as deleted on some grounds. If so, what grounds? Is [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Deleted_implicitly-declared_copy_assignment_operator) as relevant as I think it is due to a "non-trivial" element that cannot simply be copied here? Which element and why?

**EDIT** Originally this question was over-simplified and used `short thisData` rather than `CPoint thisData` due to the error messages highlighting `SomeClass::SomeClass()` as the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading your VC++ projects is intended to be a one-way forward conversion, although some effort has been put into trying to make the vcxproj files survive a round-trip conversion more robustly.

When you use Platform Toolset `v140` you are using the VS 2015 C++ compiler which is version 19.0. It is a C++11 conforming compiler, while VS 2010 (C++ version 16.0 using `v100` Platform Toolset) was a C++0x Draft supporting version.

The VS 2015 compiler will emit a number of new warnings and messages that VS 2010 would not, some of which are C++11 conformance and others which are errors about things that used to result in bad codegen. See [Breaking Changes VS 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344(v=vs.110).aspx), [Breaking Changes VS 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344(v=vs.120).aspx), [Breaking Changes VS 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx), and [Breaking Change VS 2015 Update 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt612856.aspx) to see breaking changes since VS 2010. There were also 4 updates each to VS 2012 and VS 2013 compilers, so you are basically jumping 12 releases of the C++ compiler here.

> Another major difference is that VS 2015 uses the [Universal CRT](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/).

I'm unable to repro your issue because you haven't provided enough code. The following builds just fine with VS 2015. Under `/W4` you will get a warning that you are using a nameless struct which is technically a MSVC extension, but that's it.

```
#include <vector>

class SomeClass
{
public:
    union SomeUnion
    {
        struct
        {
            short thisData;
            char thatData[ 6 ];
        };
        double otherData;
    };

    void SomeClass::GetSomeStuff( std::vector<SomeUnion> & someStuff )
    {
        someStuff.resize( 2 );
    }
};
```

You must be missing some essential issue in your repro. That said, it is quite likely that VS 2015 will emit errors/warnings that VS 2010 would not, and that's by design.

> You can write code that builds cleanly with VS 2010 - VS 2015, but it requires sticking with the C++0x language features and Standard C++ Library supported by VS 2010. You can use a few adapters to make life a little easier, but there's really no compelling reason to stick with VS 2010 for most use cases. See [Dual-use Coding Techniques for Games](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/09/17/dual-use-coding-techniques-for-games.aspx) for a tables showing the changes to the language and libraries between 2010 - 2015.
>
> Really the biggest issue is that VS 2010 uses the Windows 7 SDK while VS 2012-2015 uses the Windows 8 SDK which has some pretty major differences particularly for DirectX development. You can technically get VS 2010 to use the Windows 8 SDK via a [props](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/10/18/visual-studio-2013-and-windows-8-1-sdk-rtm-are-now-available.aspx) solution, but it's not an officially support combination.

Comment: Thanks - that looks like it will be of great help. Admittedly the code provided is an extract of a file which compiles differently in two projects, across which I thought I had done sufficient to add/remove options and lines of code to isolate the issue. Clearly not. I'll edit/update if I do isolate the issue.

Comment: Finally returned to this issue... and discovered that in extracting the essence of the problem, I over-simplified it by replacing `MyClass thisData' with `short thisData'. `MyClass` was an MFC/ATL `CPoint` courtesy of a typedef. I mistakenly assumed it was a POD type due to the error messages pointing me towards the union. But if you use `CPoint', you will be able to reproduce the error.

Comment: @omatai section 9.3 of the c++11 standard says: Note: If any non-static data member of a union has a non-trivial default constructor ([class.ctor]), copy constructor ([class.copy]), move constructor ([class.copy]), copy assignment operator ([class.copy]), move assignment operator ([class.copy]), or destructor ([class.dtor]), the corresponding member function of the union must be user-provided or it will be implicitly deleted ([dcl.fct.def.delete]) for the union.  — end note ] http://eel.is/c++draft/class.union